# Why is my code calculating incorrectly?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan

My code to calculate the dividend someone is owed is as such :

```
function ViewDividendOwed(address) public view returns (uint256) {      
  if (!RestrictedFromDividend[msg.sender]) {
    return _balances[address(this)].div(100000000).mul(_balances[msg.sender]);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

In my testing I used the following numbers:
300 for the contract holding

99,000,000 for the msg.sender balance

Which should do the following, once accounted for decimals

300/100000000*99000000 = 270

However, for some reason, it returns 2100000000000000 once accounted for decimals, and under no circumstances is it possible to reach this final answer with the numbers given. What has gone wrong?

Comment: In integer-arithmetic, `300/100000000 == 0`. Multiply before you divide! And by the way, `300/100000000*99000000 == 297` (not 270). Also, when you say that "msg.sender balance = 99,000,000", are you sure that you have checked this in `_balances[msg.sender]` and not in `msg.sender.balance`? Because the latter is Ether balance, while your computation relies on Token balance.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm getting the same error even when I switch around the multiply and divide. And yes it is _balances[msg.sender] and it is correct.

Comment: Can you log the exact values of `_balances[address(this)]` and `_balances[msg.sender]`? What is the exact formula used? You said _once accounted for decimals_ so perhaps you are doing an extra operation that alters the result.